# Cause of "no rule to make target" with make?

Tags: makefile

Isn't Makefile syntax is

```
target: require_files
   cmd...
```

Why I got this problem?

Makefile

```
MXMLC = /opt/flex/bin/mxmlc
MXMLC_RELEASE = $(MXMLC) -debug=false -compiler.optimize=true

release: bin-release/Wrapper.swf, bin-release/Application.swf

bin-release/Application.swf: src/**/*.as, lib/*.swc
    $(MXMLC_RELEASE) -output bin-release/Application.swf src/Application.as
    @@-rm ../server/public/game/Application.swf
    $(CP) bin-release/Application.swf ../server/public/game/Application.swf

bin-release/Wrapper.swf: src/*.as, src/engine/**/*.as, lib/*.swc
    $(MXMLC_RELEASE) -output bin-release/Wrapper.swf src/Wrapper.as
    @@-rm ../server/public/game/Wrapper.swf
    $(CP) bin-release/Wrapper.swf ../server/public/game/Wrapper.swf
```

$: make bin-release/Application.swf

> ~/workspace/project/src/flash [2]19:20 make: *** No rule to make
>   target `src/constant/*.as,', needed by`bin-release/Application.swf'. 
>   Stop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the commas

```
MXMLC = /opt/flex/bin/mxmlc
MXMLC_RELEASE = $(MXMLC) -debug=false -compiler.optimize=true

release: bin-release/Wrapper.swf bin-release/Application.swf

bin-release/Application.swf: src/**/*.as lib/*.swc
    $(MXMLC_RELEASE) -output bin-release/Application.swf src/Application.as
    @@-rm ../server/public/game/Application.swf
    $(CP) bin-release/Application.swf ../server/public/game/Application.swf

bin-release/Wrapper.swf: src/*.as src/engine/**/*.as lib/*.swc
    $(MXMLC_RELEASE) -output bin-release/Wrapper.swf src/Wrapper.as
    @@-rm ../server/public/game/Wrapper.swf
    $(CP) bin-release/Wrapper.swf ../server/public/game/Wrapper.swf
```

Comment: I found another question, src/**/*.as won't match src/a/b/c/d.as, can only match src/a/b.as any way to match all .as file under src

Comment: use `$(shell ...)` with something like `find`

Answer (score 2):

You can locate the files using `find`, for example:

```
ASFILES  = $(shell find src -name "*.as")
SWCFILES = $(shell find lib -name "*.swc")
```

And then use the list in your rules:

```
bin-release/Application.swf: $(ASFILES) $(SWCFILES)
        $(MXMLC_RELEASE) etc
```

I imagine you would then use the `.as` and `.swc` files in the recipe (i.e. the `$(MXMLC_RELEASE)` bit) although you don't currently.